# Animate row addition to UITableViewController with Core Data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-data, uitableview

I am working on a Core Data iPad app that uses the Master Detail design pattern. I am trying to animate adding a row after updating the `managedObjectContext`. Currently when I add an object it just appears in the table view. I am using the Stanford Core Data Table View class.

This is my add object delegate's save method:

```
 - (void)addObjectSaveButtonTapped:(iPadAddObjectViewController *)controller {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self setupFetchedResultsController];
}
```

This is my `setupFetchedResultsController` method:

```
    - (void)setupFetchedResultsController {


        NSString *entityName = @"Object";

        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

        request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"objectName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

        self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];


        [self performFetch];

    }
```

This is `performFetch` method.

```
- (void)performFetch
{
    _debug = YES;

    if (self.fetchedResultsController) {
        if (self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate) {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching %@ with predicate: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName, self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate);
        } else {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching all %@ (i.e., no predicate)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName);
        }
        NSError *error;
        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
        if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@ (%@)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
    } else {
        if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] no NSFetchedResultsController (yet?)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Is there any way to add animations to object additions?

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:yourIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

`UITableView` also has a similar method, `insertSections:withRowAnimation:`

Comment: I don't know where to put this in my code. Because the object has already been added to the `managedObjectContext` I can access it from an `NSArray` unless I know the position.

Comment: You will have to determine where (position-wise) the new row will go, and that will depend on the way you are sorting your data. You put this code in the same place you currently have `-reloadData`.